# React-router: How should I convert a routed parameter to a prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route set up:

```
<Route name="home" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="briefs" path="/briefs/:briefDate" handler={BodyBriefsList} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={BodyHome}/>
</Route>
```

And I've made a link that utilizes the route:

```
<Link to={"briefs"} params={{ briefDate: '2015-06-05' }}>View Briefs</Link>
```

I would like to save this param as a prop JS Date object in the BodyBriefsList class upon being created so that it can be used as `this.props.briefDate` Instead of `this.props.params.briefDate`which contains the string date from the path.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The props a component receives are decided by the component that renders it. You should never mutate `this.props` directly.

If you have a component that requires a certain property, and you want to bridge it with some system that doesn't provide that property directly, you should use a component to bridge the two. These are often called "container components." The only purpose of a container component is to massage data from various sources into the props that the child component needs.

```javascript
var BodyBriefsListContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <BodyBriefList briefDate={this.props.params.briefDate} />;
  }
});

<Route name="home" path="/" handler={App}>
  <Route name="briefs" path="/briefs/:briefDate" handler={BodyBriefsListContainer} />
  <DefaultRoute handler={BodyHome}/>
</Route>
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can reuse the pattern by creating a function that knows how to wrap a component and convert the props it receives into the props the wrapped component needs.

```javascript
var wrap = function(Component, propsTransformer) {
  return React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var childProps = propsTransformer(this.props);
      return <Component {...childProps} />;
    }
  });
}

var BodyBriefsListContainer = wrap(BodyBriefsList, function(props) {
  return { briefDate: props.params.briefDate };
});

<Route name="home" path="/" handler={App}>
  <Route name="briefs" path="/briefs/:briefDate" handler={BodyBriefsListContainer} />
  <DefaultRoute handler={BodyHome}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: It seems a little verbose to create a whole class for it, but I suppose the bridge analogy makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest this way :

```
 //in BodyBriefLists component
componentWillMount: function(){
  var paramDate = this.props.params.briefDate
  this.props.briefDate = Date.parse(paramDate.replace(/-/g,"/"))
}
```

I hope it will help :)